# Submitting survey answers to Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

My client wants to inject a survey answers to Qualtrics, so we created duplicated surveys in a webpage and Qualtrics.

At the webpage, when user choose the answer then it should send an api to Qualtrics.

I am seeing the manual from [https://api.qualtrics.com/guides/reference/singleResponses.json/paths/~1surveys~1%7BsurveyId%7D~1responses/post](https://api.qualtrics.com/guides/reference/singleResponses.json/paths/%7E1surveys%7E1%7BsurveyId%7D%7E1responses/post)

```
{
  "values": {
    "distributionChannel": "string",
    "duration": 0,
    "endDate": "2021-07-28T04:29:03Z",
    "finished": 0,
    "locationLatitude": "1",
    "locationLongitude": "1",
    "progress": 0,
    "startDate": "2021-07-28T04:29:03Z",
    "userLanguage": "string"    
  }
}
```

This values are from the docs. I have no idea how to send question and answer data with this API. The values from the docs are only metadata not question and answer data.

Please help how to send question and answer data to Qualtrics to submit the values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Get Response](https://api.qualtrics.com/guides/reference/singleResponses.json/paths/%7E1surveys%7E1%7BsurveyId%7D%7E1responses%7E1%7BresponseId%7D/get) API to get a single response, then use the format of values in the response to populate the question/answer pairs in the Create a New Response API call.

Comment: { "result": ..., "questions": ..., "meta":... } as per return of Get Response, I cannot find which one to put as question/answer pairs...